# unable to acess ProcessCpuTime,SystemCpuLoad methods

Tags: jmx, mbeans

I want to collect Operating Systems Parameters..in my mbean so that after registering it i can see those values on JConsole..I have collected some parameters but I cant collect the values for *ProcessCpuTime,SystemCpuLoad* I tried it with *OperatingSystemMXBean* interface object but it doesn't work. Also i read on google that those method needs APIs which are not supported on Windows.So is there another way to calculate those values mathematically...Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The Windows JVM implementation of [java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) is [com.sun.management.OperatingSystem](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/management/OperatingSystem.html). You can reference it directly by casting the former:

```
import java.lang.management.*;
import com.sun.management.*;
...
OperatingSystem os = (OperatingSystem)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
```

There's some variability between the Java 6 and java 7 versions of this class, which can be observed with this Groovy script:

```
import java.lang.management.*;

os = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
println os.getClass().getName();

try { println "Process CPU Load:${os.getProcessCpuLoad()}"; } catch (e) {}
try { println "Process CPU Time:${os.getProcessCpuTime()}"; } catch (e) {}
try { println "System CPU Load:${os.getSystemCpuLoad()}"; } catch (e) {}
```

**Java 6 Output:**

> com.sun.management.OperatingSystem
>
> Process CPU Time:79810111600

**Java 7 Output:**

> com.sun.management.OperatingSystem
>
> Process CPU Load:-1.0
>
> Process CPU Time:1840811800
>
> System CPU Load:0.4902940980431365

So it's not as useful as the Linux [et.al.] variant, but you might get what you're looking for.